# Counting GIS Data Points by Area, Class, and Time Intervals

Tags: geospatial, data-analysis, arcgis

How can I calculate the number of GIS data points per area, per class, and per day/month/year, given that I have a polygon layer containing date and class ID information?

The desired result should provide counts such as

"Area 1, Point count 10,"
"Area 1, Day 1, count 2,"
"Area 1, Day 2 count 3,"
"Class 1, count 10,"
"Day 1, class 1, count 5,"
"Day 1, class 1, area 1 count 5,"
and so on. What approach or tools can I use to achieve this analysis? using ArcGIS Esri software